# General solution of differential equation $y''-k^2y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that
$$
h_{L,M} = L\cosh\left(k\left[x-a\right]\right) + M\sinh\left(k\left[x-a\right]\right)
$$
is a general solution for the differential equation $y'' - k^{2}y = 0$.

Express the function *h* using an exponential function.

---

Okay so my way of going about this would be simply to start off by finding the second derivative of $L\cosh\left(k\left[x-a\right]\right) + M\sinh\left(k\left[x-a\right]\right)$ and then somehow compare that to $y'' - k^{2}y = 0$.

That seems very tedious though... unless there is some sort of a rule for finding the second derivative for something so complex. I'm wondering if there's a "better" way of approaching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, just take derivatives and plug in.

$$
\begin{align}
h&=L\cosh{k(x-a)}+M\sinh{k(x-a)}\\
h'&=Lk\sinh{k(x-a)}+Mk\cosh{k(x-a)}\\
h''&=Lk^2\cosh{k(x-a)}+Mk^2\sinh{k(x-a)}
\end{align}
$$

so then notice that, indeed,
$$h''-k^2h=0$$
so your proposed $h$ is a solution to this differential equation.

I can help withthe second part, expressing $h$ as an exponential function, but I want to see what you've tried so far, so we can help the most with what you don't understand.

Comment: Well I found two rules: 
$cosh(x)=(e^{x}+e^{-x})/2$ and $sinh(x)=(e^{x}-e^{-x})/2$.

So I suppose I could substitute those into the original equation and get $h=L((e^{k(x-a)}+e^{-k(x-a)})/2)+M((e^{k(x-a)}-e^{-k(x-a)})/2)$.

Is that correct?

Comment: That is a good way to do it!  You could also do what @gt6989b suggested, but your way is a good way to get the answer in terms of exponentials from what we already have, rather than solving the differential equation all over again in terms of exponentials.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the second derivative is trivial since:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sinh x=\cosh x,\ \frac{d}{dx}\cosh x=\sinh x$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $e^{ax}$ is a solution, find the 2 values of $a$ for which this is true, and apply the superposition principle - their linear combinatino will be a solution as well...